# Organize collection by child in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Let's say I have athletes who belong to photos that belong to albums that belong to events.

The fastest method for getting photos of an athlete is `$athlete->photos;`

If I go this direction:

```
$events= Event::whereHas('albums.photos.athletes', function ($q)
{
   $q->where('athlete_id', $this->athlete->id);

})
```

It works, but slower, and I'm not able to do things like $events->albums and only return albums that have photos of this particular athlete.

On my page, I want to display photos by event. How can I use `$athlete->photos` and then organize them by event?

I could loop through all of the photos found from `$athlete->photos` and build a new array with the hierarchy of event->album->photo but that seems really janky. Is there a better way to do this using Eloquent?

Edit:

This returns EXACTLY the data I need without the need for further queries, but it takes almost 20 seconds to finish.

```
// Get all athlete media
$competitions = Competition::whereHas('publishedAlbums.publishedMedia.athletes', function ($q)
{
    $q->where('athlete_id', $this->athlete->id);

})
    ->with(array('publishedAlbums.publishedMedia' => function($query)
    {
        $query->whereHas('athletes', function ($q)
        {
            $q->where('athlete_id', $this->athlete->id);

        });
    }))
    ->with(array('publishedAlbums' => function($query)
    {
        $query->whereHas('publishedMedia.athletes', function ($q)
        {
            $q->where('athlete_id', $this->athlete->id);

        });
    }))
    ->get();
```

With that, I can do things like $competitions->publishedAlbums and it only shows albums that have media for this athlete. BUT it takes a very long time to execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like this could be greatly simplified.

Does this get you what you need and is it any faster?

```
$competitions = Competition::with('publishedAlbums.publishedMedia.athletes')
    ->whereHas('publishedAlbums.publishedMedia.athletes', function($q)
    {
        $q->where('athlete_id', $this->athlete->id);
    })->get();
```

Comment: That works, but later doing $competitions->publishedAlbums contains ALL albums, not just albums that have media for the desired athlete.